# Magento: Problem in getting custom attribute value of a grouped product in IE and Chrome in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, custom-attributes, product, magento-1.5

$_product->getData doesn't work for grouped product image custom attribute :(

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
echo $_product->getData('item_front_view');
```

This code works for FF, Opera & Safari.
But doesn't working in IE and Chrome

I am using Magento 1.5.1.0
Here i am facing a strange problem.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? Does the data simply not show up or are there errors? What kinds of errors are thrown?  You can check the Magento logs to see if there are errors.  Also check the built-in firebug code analyzing in chrome to get any ideas.

Comment: Its showing simply no data for Chrome & IE.
But showing for FF, Safari & Opera :(
Dont know why its happening so

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved automatically after i come back to office on this day. May be its browser cache problem.

If anyone have the same problem try restarting the pc.

Comment: Chrome does alot of caching to speed up the browser, so that is a good chance.  And...IE just does things its own way from time to time so I have no idea what the source of that problem could be...